# Sorting Summed Collection by Timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

In a previous post I asked about getting totals which ended up being the `sum()` of the values in Laravel. When the data returns, however, it's only outputting the sum without any other information that would normally be output as well (eg: relations, timestamps, etc). Normally this wouldn't be an issue if I were just taking the sum of everything as one number.

Below is the hard-coded example of the visual I am recreating and below that is the data that creates it.

[image: Line Morris.JS Chart]

```
data: [{
                period: '2016-04',
                views: 2666,
            }, {
                period: '2016-05',
                views: 2778,
            }, {
                period: '2016-06',
                views: 4912,
            }, {
                period: '2016-07',
                views: 3767,
            }, {
                period: '2016-08',
                views: 6810,
            }, {
                period: '2016-09',
                views: 5670,
            }, {
                period: '2016-10',
                views: 4820,
            }, {
                period: '2016-11',
                views: 15073,
            }],
```

So without writing loops, what's the best way to go about getting the daily sum of visitors across all posts for whatever given period. Basically, one user owns many posts and each post has many visitors, so below is how I'm getting the sum of them all, but as you can see above, I need sums for each day based on the `created_at` timestamp in the visitors table.

```
return Post::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->withCount(['visitors' => function($query)
        {
            $query->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon\Carbon::now())->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon\Carbon::yesterday());
        }])->get()->sum('visitors_count');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with some input from above. I'm using the relationship to grab the content in a backwards manner, which is perfectly fine with me. Below is the final function used:

```
public function displayPeriodOverPeriodGraphics()
    {
        return dd(Visitor::all()->where('posts.user_id', Auth::user()->id)->groupBy(function($query)
        {
            return Carbon\Carbon::parse($query->created_at)->format('d');
        })->map(function($total)
        {
            return $total->count();
        }));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Im not familiar with Laravel. So I can show you how the query would be write in mySql and maybe you can translate:

You use `DATE()` to truncate the time part so every one have same date `yyyy-mm-dd`, then you can `GROUP BY` those days together to `COUNT(visitors)`

You need parameters `@user_id, @start_range, @end_range`

Be carefull how you setup `@end_range`. If you use `@end_range = 2016-11-17'` then `'2016-11-17 10:10:00'` will be out that range. So you probaly should use `2016-11-17 23:59:59`

```
 SELECT DATE(created_at), count(visitors)
 FROM posts
 WHERE user_id = @user_id
   AND created_at BETWEEN @start_range
                      AND @end_range
 GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
function postsPerPeriod()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at')->get()->groupBy(function ($date) {
        return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('m');
    });

    return $posts->map(function ($month) {
        return $month->sum('visitors');
    })->toArray();
}
```

It will group the posts by month then count the number of visitors in each  month and return an associative array of months to post. You can change the array keys by changing the format parameter of that gets passed to Carbon.

Comment: That would work in a normal setup. However, because one user is identified by their cookie value, they exist on a Visitors table. The Post's unique string is the foreign that relates each visit to a particular piece of content. So one user can visit ten pages and each is a separate entry in the visitors table (to aid with history on the visitor's behalf and stats tracking on the creator's behalf).

Answer (score 0):

The basic schema exists as such

```
Users:
-id (A user owns many posts; Each post has many visitors)
... (etc.)

Posts:
-id (this is not the primary identifier)
-uuid (this is the value that matters)
-user_id (Foreign Key)
... (etc.)

Visitors:
-id
-visitor_id
-posts_uuid (Foreign Key)
-created_at
-updated_at
```

So it has to be visitors rows created at a certain time period for any post owned by a user.